# Dúvida regex usar informação após o "_"

Tags: regex

Tenho a string:

```
NeName  =  MGLUE_EPCVMH_UGW01
```

Preciso das 3 primeiras letras após o primeiro "_"
Consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Em alguma linguagem especifica?

Answer (score 2):

A expressão regular é a seguinte:

```
_(.{3})
```

Aqui vai um teste em Javascript que mostra como ela funciona:

```js
var str = 'NeName = MGLUE_EPCVMH_UGW01';
var regex = /_(.{3})/m;
var match = regex.exec(str);
console.log(match[1]);
```